# Are .eot fonts supported via @font-face datauri on IE8?

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-8, webfonts, eot

Are .eot fonts supported via `@font-face` datauri on IE8?
Are datauris on IE8 supported only for images?

I know about the 32KB limitation. My base64 representation of the .eot font does not exceed this limit.

My css declaration goes something like this:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url(data:font/opentype;base64,B1QAAB9TAAACAAI.....);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: I would say: open IE8 and try it?

Comment: @MichaëlHompus Staggering thought :)

Comment: I too am suffereing from the same issue. I believe its because IE8 restricts datauri to certain file types:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score 0):

Data URIs should not be any issue for this...

...It should work, I have my .eot web font that works in all browsers (even IE7) by using this...but I also use WOFF/TTF/SVG also to support the rest of the browsers

```
@font-face {font-family: 'AllyourBase';
    src: url('/fonts/allyourbase.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/allyourbase.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/fonts/allyourbase.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/fonts/allyourbase.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/fonts/allyourbase.svg?#allyourbase') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Make sure IIS has the correct mime type on your local/web server (EX: ***application/vnd.ms-fontobject*** for ***.eot*** files).

Lastly....I doubt Datauri is the cause but to play it safe try without data/base64 and see if it does anything